# How do I get rid of the "Review payment" form after PayPal Express checkout?

Tags: 6, ubercart, payment-gateways

Can I somehow disable "Review payment" site after paying with "*Express Checkout*" method on PayPal?

Why is it even needed? Why do we assume that our customers who pay via PayPal "*Express Checkout*" do have a company? (There is the field "Company".)

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I got the answer and the solution on Ubercart's forum.](http://www.ubercart.org/forum/ideas_and_suggestions/29977/how_disable_review_payment_after_paypal_express_checkout)

Quoting the user *longwave*:

> "In **Drupal 6/Ubercart 2** go to
>   **`/admin/store/settings/payment/edit/gateways`** and expand PayPal Website
>   Payments Pro then Express Checkout.
>   In **Drupal 7/Ubercart 3** go to
>   **`/admin/store/settings/payment/method/paypal_ec`** and look towards the
>   bottom of the page."

I'm using D6.
Then I mentioned that I see the following message on that page:

> "**You must enable the Credit Card module** to use PayPal Website Payments
>   Pro."

... and that I didn't want to enable Credit card module while I don't need it. He said I have to, if I would like to reach "Review payment" settings:

> "**The settings are hidden here, this is a known bug.** Enable the credit
>   card module; you don't have to use it - or you should be able to
>   disable it again after changing the Express Checkout settings."

That's true, everything related to *"Review payment"* form could be set there!
I made a screenshot for others who are also struggling with this problem:

[image: Screenshot from Ubercart PayPal Website Payments Pro settings: <code>/admin/store/settings/payment/edit/gateways</code>]

Problem solved. No more unnecessary questions before purchasing. :)